# Paypal integration in php by storing user credentials

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I tried to integrate paypal in my website and I was able to implement  it . I tested the transcations with sandbox account provided by paypal. For each transaction, buyer need to enter his credit card details or other paypal account informations. So I would like to store the user credentials in my database and then at the time of transaction, make the buyer proceed with transaction without entering details again. Can you please suggest if there is any possibility for implementing this or any suggestions to do so? All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't store the buyer's PayPal credentials (because that's about the worst crime you can commit in internet security), but you can create a billing agreement with the buyer.  The billing agreement would allow you to charge the buyer, at a later date, without having to send the buyer to PayPal again to approve the payment.  This page tells you how to do it: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/